# how to make the value of a register fixed

Tags: signals, vhdl, fixed

I am doing project aiming to design a mini-mips32 cpu using vhdl and I came across one problem. In my register file,I want to make R0 equal to 0X“00000000” and fixed ,i.e,can never be changed.Here is my code:

type reg_array is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

-- signal reg_file : reg_array;

signal my_reg : reg_array :=

( 0 => "00000000000000000000000000000000",

1 => "00000000000000000000000000000000",

2 => "00000010000000100000001000000011",

3 => "00000011000000110000001100000011",

4 => "00000100000001000000010000000100",

5 => "11110000111100001111000011110000",

6 => "11110000111100001111000011110000",

7 => "11110000111100001111000011110000",

8 => "11110000111100001111000011110000",

9 => "11110000111100001111000011110000",

10 => "11110000111100001111000011110000",

11 => "11110000111100001111000011110000",

12 => "11110000111100001111000011110000",

13 => "11110000111100001111000011110000",

14 => "11110000111100001111000011110000",

15 => "11110000111100001111000011110000");

so here is the problem,R0 is a 32-bits signal,I cannot define it as a constant.So how to make it fixed?i.e,to make my_reg(0)=0X"00000000"forever? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either never write to it, or have a mux that returns zero when the read address is 0. I would go for the read, since it should have the synthesizer easily optimize the register 0 away.

```
RdSrc1 <= (others => '0') when unsigned(rdAddr1) = 0 else
                  my_reg(to_integer(unsigned(rdAddr1));
RdSrc2 <= (others => '0') when unsigned(rdAddr2) = 0 else
                  my_reg(to_integer(unsigned(rdAddr2));
```

On a side note, did you know you can input hexadecimal values for vectors? `val <= X"DEADBEEF";`. I think your register declaration could use it!

Answer (score 0):

Ryan - You don't show the logic you use to write the registers but typically I would mask the write to a specific index if its a read only location.

I typically use offset 0x0 in a CSR as a revision register and when I decode the address if it matches 0x0 and is a write, I complete the write but don't update the register. For a read return the value.

Kevin.